# trying to display information from an object of a NSMutable array that is in AppDelegate from another class with a dot operator

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, appdelegate

I am trying to figure out how to access and display info from an object from a NSMutable array that is created in my AppDelegate.

From my AppDelegate.h

```
@property (readonly, retain) NSMutableArray *myRaces;
@end
AppDelegate * appDelegate;
```

From my AppDelegate.m

```
extern AppDelegate * appDelegate;
@synthesize myRaces;
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
appDelegate = self;
TheRace * orc;
orc = [[TheRace alloc] init];
orc.raceTitle = @"Orc"; [orc modifyStatsFromRace:(NSString*)orc.raceTitle];
NSLog(@" test %d ", orc.massMod);
orc.raceData = @"Orcs are big burly stupid beasts";
myRaces = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[myRaces addObject:orc];
}
```

I want to call the value of orc.massMod from another class, and cannot figure out how. I tried.

```
appDelegate.raceSelected = @"Orc";
NSLog(@"Orc");
appDelegate.theMass = appDelegate.myRaces.orc.massMod;
```

However, "appDelegate.theMass = appDelegate.myRaces.orc.massMod;" failed, the error says
 ... Property "orc" not found on object type 'NSMutableArray *'

How do I call that info? I want to display the value of massMod, which works in the NSLog from within appDelegate. "appDelegate.theMass" is what holds value for display in my UILabel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are storing `orc` in an array, you cannot access it by the name of the variable. You should be able to retrieve it by calling `objectAtIndex`, e.g.

```
appDelegate.theMass = ((TheRace*)[appDelegate.myRaces objectAtIndex:0]).massMod;
```

Comment: You should remove the ".orc" part from your code, since the "objectAtIndex:0" part already returns the object called orc.

Comment: This worked perfect! Thank you so much ... I will end up trying the other methods as well for the purpose of learning. This was perfect for what I wanted. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

When you're in another class from Appdelegate and call "appDelegate.myRaces", you got a NSMutableArray. Thus you cannot access the orc object by appending ".orc", because orc is not an attribute of NSMutableArray.

You can write instead

```
// The cast is not necessary, but is useful for readability
TheRace * myOrc = (TheRace*)[appDelegate.myRaces objectAtIndex:0];  
appDelegate.theMass = myOrc.massMod;
```

but you can easily lost track of which item goes with which index. You can use too an NSMutableDictionary :

-in your AppDelegate.h

```
@property (readonly, retain) NSMutableDictionary *myRaces;
```

-in your AppDelegate.m :

```
myRaces = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[myRaces setObject:orc forKey:@"Orc"];
```

-in your other classes :

```
TheRace * myOrc = (TheRace*)[appDelegate.myRaces objectForKey@"Orc"];  
appDelegate.theMass = myOrc.massMod;
```

Comment: Your explanation is awesome. I would recommend separating the read into two lines, one puts Orc into a temporary TheRace* variable, and the other reads the attribute from it. I tend to favor readability over reduction in this type of situation. In fact, I will see if I have enough rep to edit this

Comment: Thanks for your comment, the answer had just been edited following your advice to be easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do define a macro like this:

```
#define MyAppDelegateObject ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate])
```

and refer your properties in appdelegate like this:

```
NSLog(@"Races: %@",MyAppDelegateObject.myRaces);
```